# How can I tell what resolution a VM is running at with VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtualization, virtualbox

I have some VirtualBox VMs running. Is there any way to programatically get the resolution they are running at? The guest VMs are running Windows XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the output of `vboxmanage showvminfo <name>|<uuid>`. For example:

```
C:\> vboxmanage showvminfo "Dev Server"
...
Video mode:      1360x768x32
...
```

You can also add the `--machinereadable` flag to make parsing easier. It outputs the information as key-value pairs:

```
VideoMode="1360,768,32"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution : Write a program to get the screen resolution and store it to a shared location or send it via network to the host machine. Put this program in the startup of each VM.